# Creating union of polygons with multiplying attribute table value in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, union

I am new to QGIS.

I want to do union of two polygons A and B in such a way that one of the field values in attribute tables of A and B should be multiplied in the resultant union polygon C.

How can I do this in QGIS Modeler in one go?

Answer (score 1):

ModelBuilder is easy to use If You want to run simple tools.

Try to do it like it's presented on this image:
 [image]

Blues are the polygons, yellow one is the tool You want to use and green is the result.

Comment: Thanks, First of all i forgot to mention that I want to do this step in QGIs. Secondly you only showed union but what I want is, the union should be in such a way that resultant polygon should have a field where values comes from multiplication of a field from input polygons

looking for an answer

Thank

Comment: Do as @icelandico suggests in QGIS then add your third field and compute.